# Android app using cpu when app closed with back or home - animations in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation, androidsvg

I have an app that has animations in fragments in a ViewPager. I have the ViewPager displaying on the empty option of a list fragment. The animations are NineOldAndroids ObjectAnimators combined in AnimatorSets some of which animate SVGs shown with svg-android.

When I change page on the ViewPager the animations stop using this code in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) { 
        if (myAnimationView != null) {
            myAnimationView.restartAnimation();
        }
    } else { 
        if (myAnimationView != null) {
            myAnimationView.stopAnimation();
        } 
    }
}
```

And this code in the View implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener:

```
    public void stopAnimation() {
        endAnimCalled = true;
        myAnimatorSet.end(); 
    }

    public void restartAnimation() {
        endAnimCalled = false;
        if (!myAnimatorSet.isStarted()) {
            myAnimatorSet.start();
        }
    }
```

If pressing back to exit when not on the animation page, the app uses 1-5% CPU even after several hours. If back is pressed on the page when animating, the app uses 10-30% CPU when running in the background.

Is there a good way to pass through the fragments that onPause has been called? Any ideas why the app still uses 1-5% CPU when the animations have stopped?

I have found this impossible to replicate in an app small enough to be reasonable to post on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure that the animation ends is the only solution I have found for the CPU usage. I have set it to only repeat the animation 10 times. I also considered using a BroadcastReceiver to pass a broadcast from the onPause() of the activity to call endAnimation() in the fragments.

```
    public void startAnimation() {
        createAnimation();
        animRepeats = 0;
        if (!myAnimatorSet.isStarted()) {
            myAnimatorSet.start();
        }
        AnimatorListener myAnimListen = new AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                if (!endAnimCalled && animRepeats < 10) {
                    myAnimatorSet.start();  
                    animRepeats++;
                }
            }
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
        };

        myAnimatorSet.addListener(myAnimListen);
    }

    public void stopAnimation() {
        endAnimCalled = true;
        myAnimatorSet.end(); 
    }

    public void restartAnimation() {
        endAnimCalled = false;
        if (!myAnimatorSet.isStarted()) {
            animRepeats = 0;
            myAnimatorSet.start();
        }
    }
```